# Get Boostrap activeTab on a specific nav-tabs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've always been using the code below to find the active tab but now there are two Navs in the view and the code fires for both. How to make it fire only with one of the Navs ?

```
var activeTab = "";
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) { activeTab = e.target.hash; });

<div id="tabAAAA" class="tabbable">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   ...........
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="tabBBB" class="tabbable">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   ...........
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please setup JsFiddle or insert [runnable code](http://imgur.com/a/sjCS7)

Answer (score 0):

The tab has to be unique try adding `aria-controls="1"` and adding `id="1"` in the tab panel.